# JSON loop though Google geocode address_components with Perl

Tags: json, perl, google-maps, google-geocoder

I have written a script to grab some info from google geocoder using perl and json. This example below grabs address info using an airport abbr.

```
use JSON;
use LWP::Simple;

my $geo_url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=PHL";

my $response = get($geo_url);
my $json = decode_json($response);

my $location = $json->{results}[0]->{geometry}->{location};
my $address  = $json->{results}[0]->{formatted_address};

print "<br />Latitude: ".$location->{lat}." Longiude: ".$location->{lng};
print "<br />Address: ".$address;
```

I can grab individual parts of the address_component array by using:

```
$json->{results}[0]{address_components}[0]->{short_name};
$json->{results}[0]{address_components}[1]->{short_name};
```

but what I really want to do is get the city, state and zip (postal_code). to do this I need to loop through the address_components and run something like this:

```
for (keys $json->{results}[0]{address_components}) {
  if ($json->{results}[0]{address_components}[$i]->types[0] eq "postal_code") {
    print "Zip: ".$json->{results}[0]{address_components}[$i]->{short_name};
    }
  }
```

Obviously this is not valid code but I wanted to explain what I am trying to do. It's the loop I can't get to work. I've tried a lot of configurations and I keep getting an array length of 1 even though the array item length is 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on

```
$json->{results}[0]{address_components}[0]->{shortname};
$json->{results}[0]{address_components}[1]->{shortname};
```

`$json->{results}[0]{address_components}` holds a reference to an array. While you can technically call `keys` on an array reference to get a list of indexes in recent versions of Perl, it's simpler just to get a list of the array's elements in this case (and most other cases too).

```
for my $address_component (@{ $json->{results}[0]{address_components} }) {
    if ( $address_component->{types}[0] eq "postal_code") {
       print "Zip: $address_component->{shortname}\n";
    }
}
```

Might be better to look at all the types.

```
for my $address_component (@{ $json->{results}[0]{address_components} }) {
    if (grep { $_ eq "postal_code" } @{ $address_component->{types} }) {
       print "Zip: $address_component->{shortname}\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank's, this worked out great. In case anyone wants to use this solution you may want to change shortname to short_name to be compatible with Google geocoder output. That was my bad in the original question.